# How to enable selecting new e-mails when Outlook add-in is open?

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I'm creating an add-in for Outlook (Desktop Version, not Online) using Visual Studio 2017. The main intent for the application is to extract attachments and upload to specified SAP records. This could typically be notifications, PurchaseOrders etc.

The add-in works by opening a form where you can select from options like zipping the files, delete files from e-mail, upload the e-mail it self etc.

My challenge is that the add-in works for the e-mails selected when you open the add-in. But to select new e-mails you'll need to close the form, select new e-mails and then re-open/run the add-in. Basically the add-in form is acting as a dialog box and the Outlook explorer window is in-active. Is there a setting or any thing that will allow me to select new e-mails when the form/dialog box is open or is this somethinig I'll have to live with?

Thanks for your support.
BR
Fnk

Comment: Don't open the form modally??

Comment: Or create a task pane in Outlook Explorer.

Comment: Hi Eric. It may be opened modally. Why is kind of what I'm looking for and how to change that. The load form call is the standard:

Comment: Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  <br/> Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. Found the answer in one of my books: "Sams Teach Yourself: Visual Basics 2015". (Apparently in 24 hours if you can plough through 600 pages in that time).

Anyway, I was looking in the Load Form and not the Show Form code. Somehow I'd used `frm.ShowDialog()` rather than `frm.Show()`. Apparently the `ShowDialog()` method opens the form as Modal while Show() opens as non-Modal.

As a result the code for the Ribbon button now is as follows:
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon

```
Public Class Ribbon1

   Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) _
   Handles Button1.Click

       Dim frm As MainForm    'Define a form object

       frm = New MainForm()
       'frm.ShowDialog()        'Method opens form object as Modal
       frm.Show()              'Method opens form object as non-Modal
   End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this may help someone else on the same experience level as myself.